# How to go about building a backend for an IOT Device?

Tags: firebase, mqtt, iot, esp8266

I am building an IOT device whose state is controlled by a mobile app. How do I go about building a backend for this service which can allow the device to continuously listen to any changes in state on server side?

Specifically : will cloud Firestore be appropriate for this? Or MQTT?

Comment: This question is far to broad to get proper answer here, it also doesn't show any signs that you have done any research before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the tag firebase in your question, narrowing down the possibilities to only using firebase, you can use Firebase for real time listening to commands. Firebase comes with Realtime Database that can be used to listen to change in information in real time, other than that you can also use cloud Functions and make them listen to changes on certain fields inside the database.

Comment: What about Cloud Firestore (as opposed to Realtime Database)?

Comment: @Amorphous they both are good, they have their own usage, realtime is used for not so nested database, real time access and easy manipulation, while firestorm is for sophisticated access and sophisticated manipulation, its near real time but with more nesting and referencing available, both are good!